# Get the next key from array from string with symbols

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on a simple but difficult problem for me right now, I'm use to work in jQuery but need this to be done in Javascript.

So simple as it is, the user inputs a string lets say: 
"hey, wanna hang today?". It should output the next character in my array, so it would be like this: "ifz, xboob iboh upebz?". 
And I have tried everything I can come up with. Hopefully some of you guys see the problem right away.

I have set up a short [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hs15f0kd/3/) that shows similar to what I got.

```
function gen() {
var str = document.getElementById('str').value,
    output = document.getElementById('output');
var alph =  ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','æ','ø','å','a'];
for (var i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
    var index = str[i].charAt(0),
        e = alph.indexOf(index);
    console.log(alph[e + 1]); 
    output.innerHTML += alph[e + 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: As I can see, it all works?

Comment: It works with the letters, but not with space or symbols like ', ? !' etc.

Comment: Ah, I see. Let me check...

Comment: Can you first convert each char to ascii and add one to the value? Then turn it back in to characters?

Comment: Wouldn't you need to add `?`, `!` and other symbols to your `alph` array? In your code snippet, I only see lower case letters and a few accented characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to skip to next letter with those chars and leave the others like space and `?` as they are:

```
    var index = str[i].charAt(0),
        e = alph.indexOf(index);
    if(e == -1){
        output.innerHTML += index;
    }else{
        output.innerHTML += alph[e + 1];
    }
```

Update: using @David Thomas method, you could do the following: (wouldnt work for 'å' though)

```
var index= str[i].toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0);
    if((index > 96 && index < 123)){ // a to z
        output.innerHTML += String.fromCharCode(str[i].charCodeAt(0)+1);
    }else{
       output.innerHTML += str[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: That's nice. I edited my answer for a more "specific" answer. ; )

Comment: @DOCASAREL yup, will be helpful for others!

Answer (score 2):

I'd personally recommend the following approach, which should work with any alphabet for which there's a Unicode representation and, somewhat importantly, doesn't require a hard-coded array of letters/punctuation for each language:

```
function gen() {
    var str = document.getElementById('str').value,
        strTo = '',
        output = document.getElementById('output');
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        strTo += String.fromCharCode(str[i].charCodeAt(0) + 1);
    }
    output.textContent = strTo;
}

// hey, wanna hang today? -> ifz-!xboob!iboh!upebz@
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hs15f0kd/7/).

References:

- [`String.prototype.charCodeAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt).
- [`String.prototype.fromCharCode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode).

Comment: Wow, that's well-founded!!

Comment: This looks good, but again. The output will be wrong, but I sure will use this sometime ;)

Comment: Then you really need to update your question to explain precisely what you expect. This may be obvious to you, but I certainly seem to have missed something...

Comment: Sorry, but I did wrote how the ouput should be.

Comment: Yes, but you haven't told me where this answer is wrong, or explained the output in your question. I'm not trying to be argumentative, just trying to clarify what output (and, importantly, *why*) you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Why does `gen(',') === 'a'`?

```
var alph = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
var e = alph.indexOf(',');
console.log(e);
// -1
console.log(alph[e + 1]);
// 'a'
```

You need to take this case into account; otherwise, any characters that aren't in `alph` will map to `'a'`.

(I see that you've also duplicated `'a'` at the start and end of `alph`.  This works, though it's more common either to use the modulus operator `%` or to check explicitly if `e === alph.length - 1`.)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add an array with the non respected characters:

```
var ex = ['?','!',' ','%','$','&','/']
```

In whole

```
for (var i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
    var index = str[i].charAt(0)
    if (alph.indexOf(index) >-1) {
        var e = alph.indexOf(index);
        output.innerHTML += alph[e + 1];
    } else {
        var e = index;
        output.innerHTML += e;
    }
}
```

#### JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/hs15f0kd/8/.

Comment: Well, since I need to get the 1 higher key from the array. a = b, c = d and so on. So '?' = !. That would be wronge.

Comment: Yeah, you had to specify that. What would be the right for `?`?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Only letters should replace with the higher key. I did wrote what I want the output to be like.